# VueJS - Cannot import a computed property from another computed property

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex, vue-options-api

I use a computed property for fetching me an id param in the route URL like this :

```
export default defineComponent({
  computed: {
    extractionId() : string {
      return this.$route.params.id as string;     
    },
    releves() {
      let extractionId = this.extractionId;
      return this.$store.getters.getExtractionById(extractionId)
    }
  },
// ....
```

But I have an error in `releves` when I want to access `this.extractionId`, I have this error showing :

```
Property 'extractionId' doesn't exist on type 'CreateComponentPublicInstance<{ [x: `on${string}`]: ((...args: any[]) => any) | undefined; } | { [x: `on${string}`]: ((...args: never) => any) | undefined; }, {}, {}, {}, {}, ComponentOptionsMixin, ComponentOptionsMixin, ... 10 more ..., {}>'.
```

Can't I depend on another computed property ?

Answer (score 2):

The error message isn't helpful at all. Actually, Typescript isn't happy because **both of the computed properties must declare their return type**. My `releve` property wasn't declaring its return type, so I did :

```
  export default defineComponent({
    computed: {
      extractionId() : string {
        return this.$route.params.id as string;
      },
      releves(): number[] {
        let extractionId = this.extractionId;
        return this.$store.getters.getExtractionById(extractionId).releves
      }
    },
```

And I'm free to go.

Ref: https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#typing-computed-properties

Comment: "a computed property must always declare a return type" - I don't think so. Return type is inferred from return value. As long, as its type is correct, return type (`: number[]`) can be omitted

Comment: That's what I thought, but here simply annotating the `releves` function made the error disappear.

Comment: Did you try `as number[]` instead?

Comment: [Typing Computed Properties](https://vuejs.org/guide/typescript/options-api.html#typing-computed-properties)